# модификатор доступа класса на UML диаграмме

Tags: java, uml

Как на UML диаграмме указать модификатор доступа для класса для полей и методов +/- все понятно , а вот java-класс может быть public и default но нигде про модификаторы доступа класса информации нет. Вроде логично использовать те же что для полей и методов, как правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Напротив названий класса также можно ставить обозначения модификаторов доступа. Инфы как таковой нет на счет обозначения классов, но в универе так делали все. В принципе на хабре тоже так делают: https://habrahabr.ru/post/150041/
Полистай и увидишь.